# Ideal workflow for lighting / rendering / compositing animation with multiple shots in one blender file

Tags: rendering, animation, compositing-nodes, video-sequence-editor

Usually when I work on an animation project I split it in one blend file per shots, then rendered each one in EXR, then do the compositing in After Effects.

**From now, I would like to composite in Blender to stop switching back and forth between programs.**

Let's say I have an animation with 8 camera shots.
In my blend file I first did the layout (one camera per shots), then I split it in 8 scenes inside the blend file.

After I did the animation and lighting in each of these scenes.

Now I have to render and composite the whole thing...
I setup the compositor for each scenes, that's the easy part.
The I create an empty scene only for the VSE and I put all the shots after each others in the timeline.

When I hit render sequence, *it works...* but I only get the final composite, not all the render passes.
**Moreover the file is less stable**, if hit escape during the rendering on the VSE scene Blender crashes. If I hit render on a shot scene, Blender hangs.

I suppose that these behaviors shows that I missed something but I can't tell what.

Is this workflow good ? Or do you have others inputs ?
Also, if I want to keep all my render passes I have to setup a File Output Node in the compositor right ?

Thanks everybody !

Comment: Is this a good workflow? Subjectively, no. Continue to compile your multi-shot-edit in AE.

Comment: You can keep your render passes by rendering directly to multilayer exr in Properties>Output. OR manually set the output with the file output node.

Comment: Haha, thanks @Leander. Compose all the shots in AE works for years so I guess I will have to stick with it. 

I'm curious though, if you want to do the compositing in Blender, you do it file by file, render it then edit the sequence in Premiere ? But if you have any modification on the compositing, you have to rerender it again, then do a new export of the sequence from Premiere ? (that's the kind of thing I would like to avoid with the new workflow)

Comment: As for the Multilayer EXR, it works fine in the scene containing the shot, but not in the scene with the VSE. I had to setup a file output node in the "shot scene" for it to work in the "VSE scene".

Comment: Separate the rendering process and compositing process. Render to images (multiple sequences or a multilayer exrs) and the use a new blend file or new scene for the compositing, where you just load the rendered images.

Comment: Having a gigantic setup that renders, composites and compiles all scenes in one click may be compelling, but is futile. Break down the process into meaningful stepsIf you move the data forward using exrs you don't loose enough quality in the process for it to matter.

Comment: You saw it right, I'm mainly looking to speed up all the lookdev validations steps by having Blender processed everything in one click. 
For the end of this project I'll try this : during the production one scene per shot with a compositing pass for each one. Like this I can quickly export composited previews for each shots. For the final render I will keep this setup, but keeping all the passes on a Multilayer-EXR like this if I have anything to modify I'll just have to change the input from Render Layer to Image Sequence and reconnect the passes. No re-render.